# ColdFusion Reg expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a csv file composed from a header line (field list) and several detalis lines (details for each Customer).

This file contain a lot of unused fileds so I tried to rebuild a clean file in which I put only fields I need.

for that I loop over the header line, I get the index (position) of the field I need and stored it in a variable:

```
<cfset FirstName_Pos = listfind(header,'FirstName',';')>
<cfset LastName_Pos = listfind(header,'LastName',';')>
```

The separated header fields is the ';' character.

After that I retreive the positions of all needed fields, I create a new file to put in the desired info of each line

```
<cffile action="rename" source="#LocalPath#/#FileName#" destination="#LocalPath#/Source_#FileName#">
<cfset NewFile = FileOpen('#LocalPath#/#FileName#','Append')>
<cfset Newheader = 'FirstName,LastName'>
<cfset fileWriteLine(NewFile, Newheader)>

<cfloop file="#LocalPath#\Source_#FileName#" index="line">
<cfset count = count + 1>
<cfif count GTE 2>
    <cfset FirstName= listgetat(line,FirstName_Pos,';',1)>
    <cfset LastName= listgetat(line,LastName_Pos,';',1)>
    <cfset detail = '#FirstName#,#LastName#'>
    <cfset fileWriteLine(NewFile, detail)>
</cfif>
```

The problem is that in the details lines of the original file there are some fields written as follow :

```
"#08/04/14 23:00;08/05/14 23:00#"
```

i.e the field contains the ';' character which is my separated fields character I used in the listgetat function

Therefore, I get non desired value in the variable FirstName and LastName.

Considering that the original file contain the following info:

```
USERID;Post;FirstName;Date1;Mail;Date2;LastName;Telephone
123;Engineer;Alan;"#08/04/14 23:00;08/05/14 23:00#";alan@yahoo.fr;"#10/04/14 11:00;10/05/14 11:00#";Jones;0624262589
```

I get :

```
FirstName;LastName
Alan;"#10/04/14 11:00
```

instead of

```
FirstName;LastName
Alan;Jones
```

I get the idea to loop over all details line of the original file and replace the ';' charcater with a space or blank character using regular expression only on fields having the same format "#08/04/14 23:00;08/05/14 23:00#".
(The date change of course from one field to another and from one raw to another)

```
    <cfloop file="#LocalPath#\Source_#FileName#" index="line">
<cfset newline = rereplace(line,'"##[^\w.];[^\w.]##"','"##[^\w.] [^\w.]##"','all')>
<cfset count = count + 1>
    <cfif count GTE 2>
        <cfset FirstName= listgetat(newline,FirstName_Pos,';',1)>
        <cfset LastName= listgetat(newline,LastName_Pos,';',1)>
        <cfset detail = '#FirstName#,#LastName#'>
        <cfset fileWriteLine(NewFile, detail)>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

It doesn't work because it seems that the regular expression I used is completely wrong. And also maybe because I duplicate the # sign to deal with coldfusion syntax error

Can anyone has an idea about the regular expression I have to used to deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance

this is an example of an original file

```
USERID;Post;FirstName;Date1;Mail;Date2;LastName;Telephone
123;Engineer;Alan;"#08/04/14 23:00;08/05/14 23:00#";alan@yahoo.fr;"#10/04/14 11:00;10/05/14 11:00#";Jones;0624262589
```

Comment: What if you remove all `"..."` with `"[^"]*";` regex and then use the `listgetat`?

Comment: No in fact I also want to retreive the date fields (Date1 and Date2)

Comment: Try reading your file using cfhttp.  If you include a name attribute you get a query object which might be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

parse the original file and replace all occurrences of 0;0 (number;number) with 0,0 (number,number).  Then your original solution should work fine.

regex = "/d;/d" to track them down I believe.